# Interface Builder Plugin crash with assetLibrary:didFinishDraggingAssets:info:shouldSlideBack:

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I created Plugin  for providing access to my Frameworks objects. Objects are working good except one controller. When I drag him from library to file arise very interesting assert.

```
Assertion Message: An exception was raised while -[IBLibraryController assetLibrary:didFinishDraggingAssets:info:shouldSlideBack:] was executing.
```

**One more interesting thing:** if files in .xib window stay in list mode - drugging complete without problems. Even if files stay in icon mode and I do double click on my object in library it go to the .xib file without problems.

Every body know why it is happens? I can't find any manuals about IBLibraryController class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.
If you have the same - be sure that your object implements -ibDefaultImage  method.